# What is the role of fictitious force in simple harmonic motion?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, acceleration, spring, oscillators

While I was searching about simple harmonic motion, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_harmonic_motion) defined it as,

> "**In mechanics and physics, simple harmonic motion (sometimes abbreviated SHM) is a special type of periodic motion of a body resulting from a dynamic equilibrium between an inertial force, proportional to the acceleration of the body away from the static equilibrium position and a restoring force on the moving object that is directly proportional to the magnitude of the object's displacement and acts towards the object's equilibrium position**."

However, I don't understand why a fictitious force is necessary. Our physics textbooks don't really talk about inertial forces (while defining simple harmonic motion) so I was wondering what the page would have meant when they said "a dynamic equilibrium between restoring force and inertial force". Could someone explain?

Comment: I am not keen on the definition given by Wikipedia as one can define shm in kinematics with the acceleration proportional to the displacement from a fixed point and always directed towards the fixed point.

Comment: I don't see the word "fictitious" in the quote you provided. Why are you using that language and which force do you think is "fictitious"?

Comment: @hft "Inertial force" is another name for (or a type of) "fictitious force."

Answer (score 4):

This is not a good description of simple harmonic motion. I can't understand why the concept of inertial force is in the first paragraph of this article when it isn't mentioned anywhere else. Cutting out the dynamical equilibrium part results in a much more comprehensible definition:

> In mechanics and physics, simple harmonic motion (sometimes abbreviated SHM) is a special type of periodic motion of a body resulting from a restoring force on a moving object that is directly proportional to the magnitude of the object's displacement and acts towards the object's equilibrium position.

The [edit adding the fictitious force wording](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Simple_harmonic_motion&diff=1123780402&oldid=1122470623) was only added in November 2022. I have edited the introduction to remove the mention of fictitious forces.